# Truncate time from NSDate SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

i want to get current date as SEP 15,2015.I tried first removing the time from NSDate using as

```
  let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
  let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: date)
  let currentdate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(components)
  println(currentdate)
```

However that doesnot truncates time also used this method and it gives me individual components

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: date)
let year =  components.year
let month = components.month
let day = components.day
let monthname = components.weekday
```

But the problem is i get the month in `int` with the second method.I want correspondoing `1` as `January`.How do i acheive my result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to print the current date in your desired format:

```
let today = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(0)     

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle

let dateToPrint: NSString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(today) as NSString

println(dateToPrint.uppercaseString)
```

Comment: can you say how can i get month name" Sep" as SEP

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please accept it  it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSDateFormatter to format your date like this

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"
print(formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))
```

Comment: can you say how can i get month name" Sep" as SEP

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the question..i should learn about `dateFormatter`.i got month name from number so problem solved,but if there is better way to do it..please say

```
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: date)

    let year =  components.year
    let month = components.month
    let day = components.day

    let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    let months = dateFormatter.shortMonthSymbols
    let monthSymbol = months[month-1] as! String
    println(monthSymbol)
```

Comment: checkout my answer, no need to use `NSCalendar`